# Unit test - how to check that a class accessed external resources in parallel?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have a class which reads some data from web services.
It is supposed to do it in parallel.
I want to write a unit test to ensure it does it in parallel and not sequentially.

I have replaced a web service by a stub which generates a delay (eg 1 second).
I measure the total execution time. If the method call took less than (delay * 1.1), I assume that processing happened in parallel and the test passes.

Is there a more elegant way to implement this test (eg by measuring number of threads)?

PS The class is currently using TPL to implement parallel calls:

```
IEnumerable<Task<ItineraryExternalReference>> asyncTasks = from dataSourceSiteId in dataSourceSiteIds
                                                           select this.ProcessBookingAsync(dataSourceSiteId, booking);

var externalReferences = await Task.WhenAll(asyncTasks);
return externalReferences;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an "asynchronous signal" (`TaskCompletionSource<T>`) to control your unit test stubs. In this case, something like this:

```
class WebServiceStub : IWebService
{
  public int RequiredConcurrentRequests = 2;
  private TaskCompletionSource<object> _signal = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
  async Task<T> IWebService.ProcessBookingAsync(id, booking)
  {
    if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref RequiredConcurrentRequests) == 0)
      _signal.TrySetResult(null);
    await _signal.Task;
    return ...;
  }
}
```

This is not ideal, since it will actually *hang* the unit test rather than *fail* it, but that's par for the course when unit testing concurrency.

Comment: Thank you, Stephen. I am pleased to get an answer from you.